# Using Bitcoin Commands

Tags: bitcoin-core

On the page https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin it shows several commands. Is this only for the bitcoin qt or can I use a more lightweight client like Electrum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to Bitcoin-QT and the bitcoind daemon. Other clients have to provide their own command line options and API to implement this functionality. Option and command names will likely differ in syntax and semantics.

Electrum for example provides [console access](http://electrum.org/console.html) to its internals.